# PHP contact form not working properly

Tags: php, html

I'm currently working on the early stages of a contact form for a website, but it's displaying the PHP code and not executing the code.

The PHP code works when executed directly (i.e. when executed from localhost/script.php).

Here's the code:

```
    <?php 
        if ($_POST['email']<>'') {

           require_once 'Mail.php';

           $from = "mymail@gmail.com";
           $to = "myothermail@gmail.com";
           $subject = "Test subject";
           $body = "Test";

           $host = "ssl://smtp.gmail.com";
           $port = "465";
           $username = "mymail@gmail.com";
           $password = "mypassword";

           $headers = array ('From' => $from,
             'To' => $to,
             'Subject' => $subject);
           $smtp = Mail::factory('smtp',
             array ('host' => $host,
               'port' => $port,
               'auth' => true,
               'username' => $username,
               'password' => $password));

           $mail = $smtp->send($to, $headers, $body);

           if (PEAR::isError($mail)) {
             echo("<p>" . $mail->getMessage() . "</p>");
            } else {
             echo("<p>Message successfully sent!</p>");
            }

        } else { 

          <form method="post">
              <input type="text" name="nombre" placeholder="Nombre"><p></p>
              <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email"><p></p>
              <input type="text" name="telefono" placeholder="Teléfono"><p></p>
              <textarea rows=6 name="mensaje" class="span4" placeholder="Mensaje"></textarea><p></p>

              <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Enviar">
          </form> 

        }; 
    ?>
```

I am aware that the form (at the moment) isn't related to the PHP script, I'm just trying for the script to get executed.

And this is what shows when I open the HTML (https://i.stack.imgur.com/t3FZY.jpg)

Comment: You have mixed HTML and PHP without closing and opening PHP tags. WHat are you using for an editor?

Comment: please use != for not equal or event better "if(!empty($_POST['email']))". Check the php opening and closing tags, you are adding html to a php code as I see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to close the php block after the else, then open it again after the html form.

```
} else { ?>

    start html stuff...
    end html stuff

<?php
    } //end else
?>
```

Comment: Thanks!
Fixing this, plus changing the extension to .php from .html fixed it

Answer (score 0):

replace

```
  <form method="post">
      <input type="text" name="nombre" placeholder="Nombre"><p></p>
      <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email"><p></p>
      <input type="text" name="telefono" placeholder="Teléfono"><p></p>
      <textarea rows=6 name="mensaje" class="span4" placeholder="Mensaje"></textarea><p></p>

      <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Enviar">
  </form>
```

with

```
  echo '<form method="post">
      <input type="text" name="nombre" placeholder="Nombre"><p></p>
      <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email"><p></p>
      <input type="text" name="telefono" placeholder="Teléfono"><p></p>
      <textarea rows=6 name="mensaje" class="span4" placeholder="Mensaje"></textarea><p></p>

      <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Enviar">
  </form>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Echo the HTML form and ensure your file uses the .php extension (.php)

Answer (score 0):

Even though <> is inequality operator you could could use != operator. As the if statement only has one operator. The only difference between != and <> is precedence.

Though I would use isset

```
if (isset($_POST['email']))
```

or with empty

```
if (!empty($_POST['email']))
```

because they are more readable.

You also have mixed html with PHP. You should echo the html from PHP.

```
echo '<form method="post">
  <input type="text" name="nombre" placeholder="Nombre"><p></p>
  <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email"><p></p>
  <input type="text" name="telefono" placeholder="Teléfono"><p></p>
  <textarea rows=6 name="mensaje" class="span4" placeholder="Mensaje"></textarea><p></p>

  <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Enviar">
  </form>';
```

The errors in your comment you get because you are calling `Mail::factory` and `PEAR::isError` statically which they do not support with strict standards.

You can disable strict errors with the following function call

```
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_STRICT);
```

at the top of your code.